# How do I install SymPy?

Tags: python, math, sympy, calculus

I really want to learn how to use python for stuff like calculus, math in general. I've heard that you can use SymPy, but i have no clue as to how to download it. There aren't any plugins on pycharm. Can anyone help out? And do ya'll know a better IDE i could use to run code for maths?

Comment: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/guides/getting_started/install.html

Comment: I assume that you are a Python beginner with a question like this. I did not know how to use the terminal at all when I was at your level. So maybe a YouTube tutorial might help. Maybe see [installing packages in PyCharm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zCO3KxV2zPI) and [getting started with SymPy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNsM97lnbMs).

Answer (score 0):

To install SymPy using PyPI, run the following command

```
$ pip install sympy
```

To install SymPy using Anaconda, run the following command

```
$ conda install -c anaconda sympy
```

To install SymPy from the GitHub source, first clone SymPy using git

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sympy/sympy.git
```

Then, in the sympy repository that you cloned, simply run

```
$ python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Great you want to start coding!
Maybe take a look at this to see how to install packages in python using `pip`:

[Guide](https://datatofish.com/install-package-python-using-pip/)
Should look like this

```
$ pip install SymPy
```

In Python you import an (previously installed) package with `import package_name`. Further information can be found [here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/)

Last but not least, the [SymPy documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/guides/getting_started/install.html)